# Concatenation of string+variable in Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

In the part of cnt1, I'm trying to use an integer (called A) that I'll increase in a loop so it goes from shtSheet1 to shtSheet5. In my code, I have shtSheet$A to clarify what I want to do but I don't know if visual basic allow that kind of concatenation. I'm only used to coding bash Scripts.

```
Sub RunCompare()

Call compareSheets("PROD", "OSA", "UAT", "INT", "TEST")

End Sub

Sub compareSheets(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String, shtSheet3 As String, shtSheet4 As String, shtSheet5 As String)

Dim c As Integer, j As Integer, i As Integer, mydiffs As Integer, cnt1 As Integer, cnt2 As Integer, A As Integer, B As Integer
Dim noexist As Integer

A = 1
B = 2

cnt1 = Worksheets(shtSheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
cnt2 = Worksheets(shtSheetB).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'For each cell in sheet2 that is not the same in Sheet1, color it yellow

LoopStart:

For i = 1 To cnt2
    For j = 1 To cnt1
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(i, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            For c = 2 To 22
                If Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheetB).Cells(i, c).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(j, c).Value Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(i, c).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
                End If
            Next
        Exit For
        End If
        If j = cnt1 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
Next

A = A + 1
B = B + 1

If A <= 4 Then
    GoTo LoopStart
End If 

End Sub


Sub Clear_Highlights_this_Sheet()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange. _
Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub

Sub Clear_Highlights_All_Sheets()
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In sheets
sht.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Next
End Sub
```

I updated my full macro so it is easier to understand. It compares 2 sheets and I would like to modify it to compare 5 sheets but in a specific way, only comparing the sheets 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5.

My idea was to use the A and B and a goto to do what I want.

Comment: why don't you use a loop to compare your worksheets?

Comment: Why not save the names into an array and pass that into your sub instead of a list.  Then iterate through each item in your array.

Comment: Your solution my work Scott, I'll have a look on how to use Arrays on vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ParamArray to pass the sheet names to your sub, and loop over them.

```
Sub compareSheets(ParamArray sheets() As Variant)

    Dim vSheet As Variant 
    For Each vSheet In sheets
        cnt = Worksheets(vSheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        ' ...
    Next vSheet
```

Of course you can also work with indices:

```
    For i = 0 to 3
        cnt1 = Worksheets(sheets(i)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        ' ...
    Next i
```

Comment: I think your solution won't work for me as I need two loops, one from 1 to 4 and another from 2 to 5.

Comment: Thank you very much, using this plus a few tweaks I managed to make it work. Finally, I used an Array and did the loop with index